# I wnat to design a circuit with a DC load but need help calculating the required circuit breaker, cable etc on the AC side of the power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-protection, load, ac-dc

I need to design a circuit with a knowing DC load of 24Vdc 20 watts. Now I have a Puls PIC 120.241D power supply that I can use. My question is I need to spec the protective device on the incoming ac side of the power supply and also the incoming cables size etc. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is a XY problem. You should specify where you will install it, where the power comes from, cross sections,...etc

Comment: This also depends on the AC supply voltage, regulatory environment, and the equipment enclosure, (exposed metalwork, double insulated) among other things,

Comment: Thanks, The AC supply is 240V 50Hz. Installed in a Rittal powered coated enclosure. Yes double insulted.